# Bring Google sheet URL to a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to pull the Google spreadsheet URL into a cell within my sheet automatically.

If I copied my spreadsheet, I would like the entry to reflect the URL of the new sheet. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. It's expected that askers share a brief description of what they searched/researched about the question they are asking. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible by using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start), more specifically by using the [getUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl)

From the last link:

> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   Logger.log(ss.getUrl());

The above code snippet adds the spredsheets's URL to the logger. To add it to a cell, you could use [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))